# DaggerMock is generating unexpected instances

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, dagger-2

I have the following unit test class:

```
@Rule
public DaggerMockRule<RouteRepositoryComponent> daggerMockRule = new DaggerMockRule<>(RouteRepositoryComponent.class, new RouteRepositoryModule())
        .addComponentDependency(ApplicationComponent.class, new ApplicationModule(RuntimeEnvironment.application));

@Mock
@Local
RouteDataSource mRouteLocalDataSource;

@Mock
@Remote
RouteDataSource mRouteRemoteDataSource;

@Mock
RouteDataSource.LoadRouteCallback mLoadRouteCallback;

@InjectFromComponent
RouteRepository mRouteRepository;
```

When `mRouteLocalDataSource` is declared before `mRouteRemoteDataSource`, one of the test method fails. But, when `mRouteRemoteDataSource`is declared before `mRouteLocalDataSource`, this same test method passes.

What is the influence of the declaration order of mock objects in a test class for DaggerMock?

Source: https://github.com/orogersilva/kap-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a DaggerMock bug! I have committed a fix (and I'll release a new version soon), you can fix this problem using the commit a6d5925d76 as DaggerModk version in your gradle config.

Thanks for your report